# PHP Запуск скрипта-демона на python

Tags: python, php, ubuntu, демон

Ubuntu 18.04 
Почему при вызове моего питоновского скрипта-демона  из PHP страница бесконечно грузится? Вывод вроде как направляю в файл и использую nohup (как указанно в документации). P.S. Хочу сделать кнопку на сайте, при нажатии на которую скрипт будет вкл. и работать.

Мой php код:

```
    <?php
    $result = system('nohup python3 /home/scripts/script1.py & > output.txt', $retval);
echo $retval;
    ?>
```

Питон скрипт представляет из себя вечный цикл и записью данных в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `&` фонового запуска процесса указана в неверной позиции. И еще полезно отсоединить stdin.

Важно не указывать второй аргумент, если не хотите дожидаться завершения процесса!

```
<?php
    system('nohup python3 /home/scripts/script1.py </dev/null &>output.txt &');
?>
```

Если всё-таки важно убедиться, что Python скрипт запущен корректно, то напишите запускающий скрипт.

### start.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from subprocess import Popen

DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000000
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00004000
proc = Popen(
    [sys.executable, '/home/scripts/script1.py', 'argument1', 'argument2'],
    creationflags= DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    close_fds = True
)

# Wait a bit in case process failed to start
time.sleep(2)

if proc.poll() is not None and proc.poll() > 0:
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot start process')
```

### PHP

```
<?php
    $result = system('python3 /home/scripts/start.py 2>&1', $retval);
    echo $retval;
?>
```

Comment: процесс запускается, но страница все равно грузится бесконечно

Comment: Не указывайте второй аргумент в функции `system` - в этом загвоздка. Я исправил ответ